# Les travaux sont « en arrêt » ou sont « en arrêts » ?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, pluriel

Est-ce qu'on dit :

> Les travaux sont en arrêt.

ou bien

> Les travaux sont en arrêts.

et **pourquoi** ?

***NB***: un lien vers un cours en ligne de Grammaire/Orthographe sur le sujet serait le bienvenu.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Les travaux sont à l'arrêt.

Ils sont en état d'arrêt et pas en état de marche.

[Voici un lien wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/arr%C3%AAt) où tu peux voir qu'*être aux arrêts* a un sens différent.

Comment: _être à l'arrêt_ ou _être à l'état d'arrêt_ , on ne dit pas _être en arrêt_ ?? j'ai bien compris votre réponse ??

Comment: @OSryx On ne dira pas *"Les travaux sont en arrêt"* mais plus simplement *"Les travaux sont arrêtés"* ou *"à l'arrêt"* comme je t'ai répondu. Pour une absence pour cause de maladie, on on peut dire *"être en arrêt maladie"* mais c'est un raccourci pour dire *"être arrêté pour cause de maladie"*. Regarde les exemples du [lien wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/arr%C3%AAt) pour mieux ta faire une idée, il y a 3-4 exemples par définition.